# Jackson maps to wrong object

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I have a JSON object of type Troubleshoot that I'd like to store in the back-end. One of the parameters of this object is a list of questions

```
QuestionList: Array[1]
    0: Object
        id: 1116
        question: "Question 1"
        update: 1447842794620
```

It is supposed to be mapped to the Question object in the back-end

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Question extends AbstractNodeUpdateProperty
{

   private long mId;
   private String mQuestion;

   /**
    * No-arg constructor required for JaxB serialization.
    */
   public Question()
   {
      super();
   }

   public Question(long aId, String aQuestion, long aUpdate)
   {
      super(aUpdate);
      mId = aId;
      mQuestion = aQuestion;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public long getId()
   {
      return mId;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public String getQuestion()
   {
      return mQuestion;
   }

   public void setId(long aId)
   {
      mId = aId;
   }

   public void setQuestion(String aQuestion)
   {
      mQuestion = aQuestion;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Id: " + mId + ", question: " + mQuestion;
   }
}
```

But instead, Jackson seems to want it to map it to the Suggestion object

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Suggestion extends AbstractNodeUpdateProperty
{
   private long mId;
   private String mTitle;
   private String mActionToTake;
   private Boolean mIsIntegrated;

   /**
    * No-arg constructor required for JaxB serialization.
    */
   public Suggestion()
   {
      super();
   }

   public Suggestion(long aId, String aTitle, String aActionToTake, long aUpdate)
   {
      super(aUpdate);
      mId = aId;
      mTitle = aTitle;
      mActionToTake = aActionToTake;
      mIsIntegrated = true;
   }

   public Suggestion(long aId, String aTitle, String aActionToTake, long aUpdate, Boolean aIsIntegrated)
   {
      super(aUpdate);
      mId = aId;
      mTitle = aTitle;
      mActionToTake = aActionToTake;
      mIsIntegrated = aIsIntegrated;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public long getId()
   {
      return mId;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public String getTitle()
   {
      return mTitle;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public String getActionToTake()
   {
      return mActionToTake;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public Boolean getIsIntegrated()
   {
      return mIsIntegrated;
   }

   public void setId(long aId)
   {
      mId = aId;
   }

   public void setTitle(String aTitle)
   {
      mTitle = aTitle;
   }

   public void setActionToTake(String aActionToTake)
   {
      mActionToTake = aActionToTake;
   }

   public void setIsIntegrated(Boolean pIsIntegrated)
   {
      mIsIntegrated = pIsIntegrated;
   }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
nov 18, 2015 11:41:30 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "question" (Class com.iba.smi.troubleshooting.suggestion.Suggestion), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@28fe95ed; line: 1, column: 203] (through reference chain: com.iba.smi.troubleshooting.TroubleshootResult["Troubleshoot"]->com.iba.smi.troubleshooting.troubleshoot.Troubleshoot["QuestionList"]->com.iba.smi.troubleshooting.suggestion.Suggestion["question"])
```

Am I interpreting this error correctly? Any idea why this error occurs and how to solve it?

The Troubleshooting class
all parameters have getters and setters, but for the sake of length I shortened it a bit:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Troubleshoot extends AbstractNodeUpdateProperty
{
   private String mAlarmId;
   private ArrayList<Suggestion> mSuggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<Question> mQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<AlarmLink> mAlarmLinkList = new ArrayList<>();

   private ArrayList<SuggestionAskQuestion> mSuggestionAskQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<SuggestionAskAlarmLink> mSuggestionAskAlarmLinkList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<AlarmAskQuestion> mAlarmAskQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<AlarmAskSuggestion> mAlarmAskSuggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<AlarmAskAlarmLink> mAlarmAskAlarmLinkList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<QuestionAnswerSuggestion> mQuestionAnswerSuggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<QuestionAnswerAlarmLink> mQuestionAnswerAlarmLinkList = new ArrayList<>();

   /**
    * No-arg constructor required for JaxB serialization.
    */
   public Troubleshoot()
   {
      super();
   }

   public Troubleshoot(String aAlarmId, long aUpdate)
   {
      super(aUpdate);
      mAlarmId = aAlarmId;
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "SuggestionList")
   public ArrayList<Suggestion> getSuggestionList()
   {
      return mSuggestionList;
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "QuestionList")
   public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionList()
   {
      return mQuestionList;
   }

   public void setSuggestionList(ArrayList<Suggestion> aSuggestionList)
   {
      this.mSuggestionList = aSuggestionList;
   }

   public void setQuestionList(ArrayList<Suggestion> aQuestionList)
   {
      this.mSuggestionList = aQuestionList;
   }
}
```

Comment: how is `Troubleshoot` class defined?

Comment: @sharonbn I added it. Just a bunch of getters and setters and a toString method

Comment: I can guess that the problem is that `mQuestionList` is defined a List with generic type and at run time jackson does not have the generic type info.  did you try looking at [`@JsonTypeInfo`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonTypeInfo)

Comment: I understood that the diamond operator uses the type defined on the left hand side of the variable name.
JsonTypeInfo doesn't seem to have any effect. But thank you for thinking along.

Comment: I am not talking about the diamond operator. that is handled by the compiler. You must understand that generic type information is erased at run time. Jackson cannot tell the type of item in the `mQuestionList` list at runtime.

Comment: the actual call to Jackson's `ObjectMapper` for the deserialization - is that done by Jersey or in your code?

Comment: That is done by Jersey

Comment: What does your handler method look like?

Comment: I found the error. There's a typo in the Troubleshoot.setQuestionList() method. It takes an incorrect ArrayList of Suggestion and assigns it to the incorrect variable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. There's a typo in the Troubleshoot.setQuestionList() method. It takes an incorrect ArrayList of Suggestion and assigns it to the incorrect variable as well.